# function wait with return until $.getJSON is finished

Tags: javascript, jquery, function

I am writing a function which has to get the thumbnail information from a given video using the embed.ly API, however currently the function returns a value before it even got the JSON result from the API.

I am using the following code:

```
function getThumbnail(vUrl) {
    var thumbnail   = '';
    var title       = '';
    var caption     = '';
    var content     = '';

    $.when( $.getJSON("http://api.embed.ly/1/oembed?key=:key&url="+vurl) ).then(function(data){
        var thumbnail = data.thumbnail_url;
            console.log(thumbnail);

        return {
            thumbnail:thumbnail,
            vurl:vurl
        }
    });
}
```

However when using the Chrome Javascript console I can see that:

1. the function is called
2. undefined is returned
3. XHR request is finished
4. variable thumbnail content is shown in console

This is obviously the wrong order.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to return the response from an AJAX call?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-to-return-the-response-from-an-ajax-call)

Answer (score 39, accepted):

## Updated answer

`getJSON` returns a promise (a read-only deferred), so you can listen to it. But since you need some post-processing, you'd want to chain a `then` which allows you to alter the resolved value.

```
// Now using `then`
function getThumbnail(vUrl){
  return $.getJSON("http://api.embed.ly/1/oembed?key=:key&url="+vurl).then(function(data){
    return {
      thumbnail:data.thumbnail_url,
      vurl:vurl
    }
  });
}

//and in your call will listen for the custom deferred's done
getThumbnail('the_vurl_').then(function(returndata){
  //received data!
});
```

---

## Original answer

You can use a [deferred object](http://api.jquery.com/category/deferred-object/), and listen for the [`done()`](http://api.jquery.com/deferred.done/).

```
function getThumbnail(vUrl) {
    //create our deferred object
    var def = $.Deferred();

    //get our JSON and listen for done
    $.getJSON("http://api.embed.ly/1/oembed?key=:key&url="+vurl)
        .done(function(data){

            //resolve the deferred, passing it our custom data
            def.resolve({
                thumbnail:data.thumbnail_url,
                vurl:vurl
            });
        });

    //return the deferred for listening
    return def;
}

//and in your call will listen for the custom deferred's done
getThumbnail('the_vurl_')
    .done(function(returndata){
        //received data!
    });
```

You could return `$.getJSON`'s deferred to get the raw data. But because of "post-processing" into an object, the custom deferred is needed. You could also pass a callback to `getThumbnail()`:

```
function getThumbnail(vUrl,callback) {
    $.getJSON("http://api.embed.ly/1/oembed?key=:key&url="+vurl,function(returndata){
        callback(returndata);
    });
}

getThumbnail('the_vurl_',function(returndata){
    //received data!
})
```

Comment: thanks! The deferred method unfortunatly didnt work for me however the callback did!

Comment: I wanted to add a thank you, because this (the Deferred) fixed exactly the problem I was having with my own project. Thanks!

Answer (score 7):

Using Async/Await

```
async function getThumbnail(vUrl) {
  const data = await $.getJSON("http://api.embed.ly/1/oembed?key=:key&url="+vUrl);
  return {
      thumbnail:data.thumbnail_url,
      vurl:vUrl
    }
}

async function someFunction() {
    let thumbNail = await getThumbnail('the_vurl_');
}
```

Comment: As for today (near the end of 2021) I think this should be the right answer.

Comment: Finally, a simple example that works. Thank you

Answer (score 2):

you can simple use `$.getJSON`'s callback like following:

```
function result(res) {
  console.log(res);
}

function getThumbnail(vUrl) {
   var thumbnail   = '';
   var title       = '';
   var caption     = '';
   var content     = '';

   $.getJSON("http://api.embed.ly/1/oembed?key=:key&url="+vurl, function(data) {
     var thumbnail = data.thumbnail_url;
     console.log(thumbnail);

     var result = {
        thumbnail:thumbnail,
        vurl:vurl
      };

     // passing the result to a function
     getResult(result);

   });
}
```

**NOTE:**

You see that I'm calling a function to pass the result, where you are trying to `return`, but you can't `return` result to caller function. Because, `$.getJSON` is asynchronous.

Comment: Yes but I'm not calling another function from the getThumbnail() function, so in this case this wont work for me.