# Wait for a function to finish before assigning the return to a variable - JS

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a function that does a AJAX post request and returns the data from that request.

The problem is that when using the function the code won't wait for the function to return before containing.

How can I add a call back to a function call.

```
function apicall( data ) {
    var props = {
        data : data,
        ..
    }
    $.post( '/auth/login' , props )
    .done(function( data ) {
        var result = JSON.parse(data);
        return result;
    });
}
```

I then call the function below

```
var result = apicall( data);
```

I need to wait until *apicall* has finished before assigning the value to *result*

Answer (score 0):

found the answer in this post: using **deferred**

[function wait with return until $.getJSON is finished](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10775787/function-wait-with-return-until-getjson-is-finished?rq=1)